# Extjs 4 - FormPanel inside menu - focus issue

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have form panel as a menu item. The problem is that it constantly looses focus and standard navigation controls like tab are not working. Is there some kind of config to make this work? Notice i extend Ext.panel.Panel instead of Ext.form.Panel. When i use the second one i get `origin.on is not a function`. Here is code:

```
this.tbar = [{
    xtype: 'tbfill'
}, {
    xtype: 'tbseparator'
}, {
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'Wyszukiwanie',
    iconCls: 'icon-magnifier',
    menu: {
        focusOnToFront: true,
        items: [{
            xtype: 'decision_quicksearch',
            title: 'Panel wyszukiwania',
            iconCls: 'icon-magnifier',
        }]
    },
    listeners: {
        afterrender: function () {
            //register this btn to quicksearch panel so we can hide menu when search button is clicked
            Ext.apply(this.menu.items.items[0], {
                parentComponent: this
            });
        }
    }
}];
```

And the form:

```
Ext.define('GSIP.view.decisions.DecisionQuickSearchPanel' ,{
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',   
    alias : 'widget.decision_quicksearch',
    layout:'anchor',
    title:'Wyszukiwanie decyzji',
    frame:true,
    width:300,
    defaults: {
        anchor: '100%'
    },
    style: {
        marginLeft: 'auto',
        marginRight: 'auto'
    },
    bodyPadding:20,

    initComponent: function() {

        this.addEvents('quicksearch');

        this.items = this.createForm();

        this.buttons = [{
            text:'Szukaj',
            iconCls:'icon-magnifier',
            scope:this,
            handler:this.processForm
        }],

        this.callParent(arguments);

    },
    createForm:function() {


        var items = [{
            xtype:'textfield',
            fieldLabel:'Znak',
            labelWidth:40,
            name:'sign'
        },{
            xtype:'textfield',
            fieldLabel:'Numer',
            labelWidth:40,
            name:'number'
        },{
            xtype:'textfield',
            fieldLabel:'Rok',
            labelWidth:40,
            name:'suffix',
        }];

        return items;
    },
    processForm:function() {
        var result = this.buildFilter();
        this.fireEvent('quicksearch', result);
        this.parentComponent.hideMenu();
    },
    buildFilter:function() {
        var sign =  this.down('textfield[name=sign]').getValue();
        var number =  this.down('textfield[name=number]').getValue();
        var suffix =  this.down('textfield[name=suffix]').getValue();


        var result = new Array();
        var res = {
                name:'documents.sign',
                valuesType:'string',
                filterType:'like',
                values:[{id:1, value:sign}]
        };
        result.push(res);

        var res = {
                name:'documents.number',
                valuesType:'string',
                filterType:'like',
                values:[{id:1, value:number}]
        };
        result.push(res);

        var res = {
                name:'documents.suffix',
                valuesType:'string',
                filterType:'like',
                values:[{id:1, value:suffix}]
        };
        result.push(res);

        return result;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have accomplished a similar functionality but in a different way.
What I did is simply made the button generate an `Ext.Window` with no header and limited border and positioned it under the button on open. You can then use `MouseOut` events to close the window and it will operate just like a menu or you could put the header on the bottom and place a close tool and have the window "pin".

```
buttonClick: function (btn, e, opts) {
    var popUpWindow = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
        width: 450,
        maxHeight: 400,
        resizable: false,
        closable: false,
        title: 'Report Filters',
        headerPosition: 'bottom',
        border: false,
        draggable: false,
        bodyStyle: 'background:white;padding:5px;',
        items: [ 
    //...your form
    ]
    });
    popUpWindow.showAt(btn.getBox(false).x - 3, btn.getBox(false).y - 7);
}
```

Comment: That may be a good idea! Could You provide css You used to position new window below the button?

Comment: Ah, you did this this way. Clever! I also added constrainHeader:true to prevent window appearing outside screen (as i have my button after tbfill). Many thanks for Your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i ended up with. It seems that this is exactly as if i was using menu but using method provided by ViaoV

```
var me = this;

this.popUpWindow = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    resizable: false,
    closable: false,
    constrainHeader: true,
    title: 'Panel wyszukiwania',
    iconCls: 'icon-magnifier',
    border: false,
    draggable: false,

    items: [{
         xtype: 'decision_quicksearch',
         listeners: {
             afterrender:function(me) {
                 Ext.getDoc().on('mousedown', function(o) {
                     console.log('mousedown');
                     if (!o.within(me.getEl())) {
                         me.parentComponent.toggle(false);
                     }
                 })
//               me.getEl().on('blur', function() {
//                   console.log('blur');
//                   me.parentComponent.toggle(false);                  
//               });
             }
         },
       }]
});

this.tbar = [{
    xtype:'tbfill'
}, {
    xtype:'tbseparator'
}, {
    xtype:'button',
    text:'Wyszukiwanie',
    iconCls:'icon-magnifier',
    enableToggle:true,
    menu: { },
    listeners:{
        afterrender:function() {
        //register this btn to quicksearch panel so we can hide menu when search button is clicked
        Ext.apply(me.popUpWindow, {
                parentComponent:this
        });
        },
        toggle: function(btn, pressed) {
         if (pressed) me.popUpWindow.showAt(btn.getBox(false).x - 3, btn.getBox(false).y + btn.getBox(false).height);
         else me.popUpWindow.hide();
        }
    }
}];
```

**EDIT:** After some testing the solution i ended up with is not a good one. I have comboboxes in my panel which are defined by boundlist as another dom, so when i pick item from cbox !o.within(me.getEl()) evaluates to true and hides my panel. I really need the functionality when the user clicks elsewhere the window hides.